# Flexbox padding not distributed equally

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hey guys i am using flexbox to create a simplebox effect , now i have the following HTML:

```
<div class="main">
            <a class="info-boxes">
                <h5>2200AED</h5>
                <p>5 Private Sessions / Validity: 2 Months</p>
                <span>Online Booking</span>
            </a>

            <a class="info-boxes"></a>
            <a class="info-boxes"></a>
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,400italic,500,700,900);


/* global css */

body {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.info-boxes {
    width: 33.33%;
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    flex-direction:column;
    background: #f5989d;
    padding: 0.5em 0;
}


.info-boxes h5 {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.info-boxes span {
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.info-boxes span:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: calc(100% + 10px );
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #fff;
}

.info-boxes span:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: calc(100% + 10px );
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Now the following line of padding is applied to the main parent , just so that the children don't stick to the top or the bottom:

```
padding: 0.5em 0;
```

Now that causes the vertical alignment to break , also seemingly the padding is not evenly distributed . Why ?

**[FIDDLE HEER](https://jsfiddle.net/mk54kekv/2/)**

Comment: Here `padding: 0.5em 0;` is applied to `.info-boxes` not main parent

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Flexbox does not affect the way padding works. Can you show us that actual issue...the fiddle doesn't seem to demo the problem.

Comment: @Paulie_D see how i have applied padding:3em 0; https://jsfiddle.net/mk54kekv/4/ now you should see the uneven distribution of padding

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? - https://jsfiddle.net/mk54kekv/5/

Comment: @Paulie_D stupid question , the borders made it clear to me ! i taught the boxes were stacked against each other rather then vertically ! thanks Paul !